# Toggle bootstrap button dropdown using another button

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Been having some issues getting a Bootstrap button dropdown to toggle (making the list items and dropdown ul element visible) when another button is clicked. Here's what I have so far which doesn't seem to work (v3.3.7). I want the "testing" button to additionally toggle the "test" button dropdown.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a id="test-dropdown-btn" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Test <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul id="test-dropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<a id="test-btn" class="btn btn-default" onclick="$('#test-dropdown-btn').dropdown('toggle')">testing</a>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the custom attribute `data-target` to target the button group, so clicking on any element outside will trigger the dropping-down on the targeted button group.

```
<a id="test-btn" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target=".btn-group">
testing</a>
```

You should give your button group an id, so that the `data-target` is more specific.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gmannbr7/)

Answer (score 0):

Try `.toggle('dropdown')` instead of `.dropdown('toggle')`:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
    <a id="test-dropdown-btn" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Test <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul id="test-dropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<a id="test-btn" class="btn btn-default" onclick="$('#test-dropdown-btn').toggle('dropdown')">testing</a>
```

Comment: This makes the whole dropdown button toggle off so it's not visible. I'm thinking down the lines of making the actual ul dropdown appear.